# PyCharm 5 can't find Django 1.9 templates

Tags: django, templates, pycharm, breakpoints

When I'm debugging my app with PyCharm 5.0.3, I want to insert a few breakpoints into template files (Django 1.9).

However, when I run app in PyCharm debug mode, it prints the following warning as soon as it processes the first request.

> WARNING: Template path is not available. Please set TEMPLATE_DEBUG=True in your settings.py to make  django template breakpoints working

I've read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/upgrading/) that TEMPLATE_DEBUG has been deprecated and I already have this setting in the new format. I've also tried marking the templates directory as "Template Folder" as per another Stackoverflow post, but it doesn't help.

Has anyone seen this issue before? Here are my settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DEBUG = True
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug': DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: PyCharm is a commercial IDE. Have you tried all their official support channels? Better talk to someone that is paid to help you than wait for the goodwill of volunteers here.

Comment: Yes, I have posted a question there as well and will update this post if they reply. I thought it worth posting the question here too due to such a vast community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a reply from PyCharm, it's a known issue and will be fixed in then next release.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17923

Comment: its fixed up from version 5.0.4