# Debugging django templates in pycharm

Tags: python, django, ide, pycharm

I've set break points in the template and i run the server but pycharm doesn't seem to pick up the breakpoints for the template but only the python files. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyCharm 5 can't find Django 1.9 templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524102/pycharm-5-cant-find-django-1-9-templates)

Comment: Its a known issue that hasn't been fixed yet (as far as I know)

Comment: You might be interested to know that [Jetbrains just fixed this for me](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19342), it will be fixed in the next release. I'd add an answer but it looks more likely that this question will get auto deleted soon which is probably more appropriate

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-2-debugging-django-templates.html

Answer (score 4):

From Pycharm 2017.1
**Prerequisite**

Django is specified as the project template language.

To do that, open the Project Settings dialog, under the Project Settings select page Python Template Languages, select project where the templates reside, and then choose Django from the Template Language drop-down list.

[image]
Debugging a Django template

To debug a Django template, follow these general steps

Place breakpoints in the desired lines of the Django templates:

[image]

Launch Django server in the Debug mode.
This is how it's done:

On the main menu, choose Run | Edit Configurations.

If the desired Django Server run/debug configuration exists, select it, otherwise create a new one, as described in the section Creating and Editing Run/Debug Configuration.

Then click the button  [image] on the main toolbar, or press ⌃D.

PyCharm will open the template in your browser, and suspend at the breakpoints you've set.

The Debugger session starts, and Debug tool window appears.
In the Debug tool window, you can:

Examine the rendering contexts in the Variables pane.
Step through the breakpoints defined within the Django template.
Use the debugging console.

If you want to trace back exceptions that are raised in course of template debugging, open Breakpoints dialog,  and in the Django Exception Breakpoints tab, select the check box Suspend.

Debugging Jinja and Mako templates is not supported.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2017.1/debugging-django-templates.html